# how to use libfreenect java wrapper in processing

Tags: java, macos, kinect, processing, osx-mavericks

I have a kinect 1473, and mac osx, and I am trying to access my kinect from processing. So I saw a few options:

- use Daniel Shiffman's library
- use SimpleOpenNI

Both those options do not work, since I have the "new" kinect (apparently).

But when I install libfreenect with homebrew, and run `glview` it *just works!!* That is great news :) And I saw that libfreenect has a [java wrapper](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/tree/master/wrappers/java) but I am a completely in the blue how I should use or access it in the processing environment.

I only found this [post](http://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1124129086.html) but it did not help me much.

I am basically a java noob, so need a little beginners help here :)
Do I need to make a jar from the libfreenect java wrapper?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't exactly help you with libreenect, but maybe this will:

SimpleOpenNI's new version 1.96 did not work for me neither... What did work though was to install the older version...
Instructions are [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/wiki/Installation_PreOpenNI2) but if you try to click any links to download the files it will take you to an dead looking end... But it's not! Make sure the drop down at the top says All downloads and not Current downloads...

Short way worked for me on osx-mavericks, Processing 2.0.3 (and I think my kinect is 1473):

Download [SimpleOpenNI 0.27](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/detail?name=SimpleOpenNI-0.27.zip&can=1&q=) (proper link and version that worked for me)
Download [Installer](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/downloads/detail?name=OpenNI_NITE_Installer-OSX-0.24.zip&can=1&q=Installer%20osx) (proper link that worked for me)
Unzip the file and open a terminal window
Go to the unzipped folder 'OpenNI_NITE_Installer-OSX'

```
cd ./OpenNI_NITE_Installer-OSX
```

Start the installer

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

Move for the camera! :D

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try, and let you know.